# PSR for class names and filenames of similar classes

Tags: php, psr-1

I have a group of Serializer classes that I want to put under a namespace. How would I call those classes and their filenames according to PSR?

Should I have:

```
/Serializer
    Markdown.php (class Markdown)
    Json.php (class Json)
    Html.php (class Html)
```

```
Vendor\Package\Serializer\Markdown
```

or

```
/Serializer
    MarkdownSerializer.php (class MarkdownSerializer)
    JsonSerializer.php (class JsonSerializer)
    HtmlSerializer.php (class HtmlSerializer)
```

```
Vendor\Package\Serializer\MarkdownSerializer
```

- Should the namespace and folder name be plural, i.e. "Serializer**s**"?
- How should I capitalize JSON - `JsonSerializer` or `JSONSerializer`

---

I guess suffixing files with `Serializer` is better because if I have a base class `Serializer.php` that others extend, they would be called `FooSerializer.php` and it would make sense. Otherwise, if I have a base class, how would I call it? If I have `Serializer.php` and `Markdown.php`, nothing would indicate that one extends the other in any way.

Comment: There isn't a PSR on this topic. Any discussion would be primarily opinion based and outside the scope of SO.

Answer (score 0):

- Suffixing classes: There is only a very general [PSR Naming Convention](https://www.php-fig.org/bylaws/psr-naming-conventions/).
- Class suffixes are very common (in most cases). Example: `MarkdownSerializer`
- PSR-1: Class names MUST be declared in StudlyCaps. For example: `JsonSerializer`
- In practice the most namespaces and class names are **singluar**.